# angular-ui-bootstrap Tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Im new to ui-bootstrap. actually im trying to use some components as tabs to make a menu for my app. My solution is unfortunately not working. Who can please help. 
Here is my code.

```js
angular.module('scolarite', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.demo', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.demo', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch']).controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.tabs = [
        {title: 'Dynamic Title 1', content: 'Dynamic content 1'},
        {title: 'Dynamic Title 2', content: 'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true}
    ];

    $scope.alertMe = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $window.alert('You\'ve selected the alert tab!');
        });
    };
  
    $scope.model = {
        name: 'Tabs'
    };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="scolarite">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Accueil</title>
        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/angular-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/angular-animate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/angular-animate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/angular-touch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/angular-touch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/acc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/ui-bootstrap-2.5.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/ui-bootstrap-2.5.0.tpls.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/ui-bootstrap-2.5.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
        <style type="text/css">
  form.tab-form-demo .tab-pane {
    margin: 20px 20px;
  }
</style>
      <uib-tabset type="pills">
    <uib-tab heading="Inscription">Tab 1 content</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="Liste Etudiants" classes="btn-sm">Tab 2 content</uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply

```
$scope.groups = [
    {
      "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "Country" : "Germany",
      "open" : true
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "Country" : "Sweden",
      "open": false
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "Country" : "Mexico",
      "open" : false
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
      "Country" : "Austria",
      "open" : false
    }
  ]
```

in HTML

```
<uib-accordion close-others="true"> 
     <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="{{group.Name}}" ng-repeat="group in groups" is-open="group.open">

     {{group.Country}}
     </div>
   </uib-accordion>
```

Have a look at this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5l6g8zRw9Xe2uvkXrtMv?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are getting your modules mixed up. You have set up two modules `scolarite` and `ui.bootstrap.demo` and then you have attached the `TabsDemoCtrl` controller to one of them - the `ui.bootstrap.demo` module, yet you are using the `scolarite` module in the app's `ng-app` directive.

**To fix**, you can change your `ng-app` directive so that your app uses your `ui.bootstrap.demo` module (the one with the controller), like this:

```
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">`
```

Then you can remove the declaration of the `scolarite` module by removing this line:

```
angular.module('scolarite', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.demo', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch']);
```

**Side note**: You can do this the other way around, the key is to attach the controller to the module that you specify in your `ng-app` directive.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this solution its working fine](https://plnkr.co/edit/LchNcZQNJ7GqOEKtzcwH?p=preview)

```
  // Code goes here

angular.module('scolarite', ['ui.bootstrap.demo']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']).controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.tabs = [
        {title: 'Dynamic Title 1', content: 'Dynamic content 1'},
        {title: 'Dynamic Title 2', content: 'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true}
    ];

    $scope.alertMe = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $window.alert('You\'ve selected the alert tab!');
        });
    };

    $scope.model = {
        name: 'Tabs'
    };
});
```